# How to color background in react-native-CalendarPicker with custom Dates

Tags: react-native, calendar, background-color, android-calendar, react-native-calendars

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import CalendarPicker from 'react-native-calendar-picker';

const ChechAvailability = () => {

    const [date, setDate] = useState([]);
    const [userDate, setUserDate] = useState('');

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    axios.post("http://192.168.0.19:3000/booked_dates").then((resp) => {
          setDate(resp.data)
        });

    useEffect(() => {
        setDate(date);
    }, [date]);

    // console.log(date);

    const listItems = date.map((items) => moment(items.booking_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    // console.log(listItems);


    let today = moment();
    let day = today.clone().startOf('month');
    let customDatesStyles = [];
```

Comment: THIS IS MY CALENDAR PICKER
                <CalendarPicker
                    todayTextStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red'}}
                    todayBackgroundColor={'transparent'}
                    customDatesStyles={customDatesStyles}
                    // minDate={today}
                />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollable CalendarPicker — New in 7.x
The scrollable prop was introduced in 7.0.0 and features a bi-directional infinite scroller. It recycles months using RecyclerListView, shifting them as the ends are reached. If the Chrome debugger is used during development, month shifting may be erratic due to a RN setTimeout bug. To prevent month shifts at the ends of the scroller, set restrictMonthNavigation, minDate, and maxDate range to 5 years or less.

*strong text*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).